# CMake adding C++ header only libraries

Tags: cmake

I have several libraries that are header-only due to being templatized.

What I'd like is to provide a CMakeLists.txt under each of them that exports their include folder as an include location, if that makes sense.

```
add_library(htcw_io lib/htcw_io/src/io_stream.cpp)
target_include_directories(htcw_io PUBLIC
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/htcw_bits/include"
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/htcw_io/include"
"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

Notice how I have to include lib/htcw_bits/include despite it being a separate library than htcw_io. It's because it doesn't have any source files - only headers so I can't export it by itself as a library.

One option would be to include an empty cmake_dummy.cpp file with htcw_bits and other similar header only libraries just to give CMake something to bind to but this seems sloppy as heck. However, if that is the solution, I'll do it. I'd just like to know if there are better options.

Surely, they've thought of this use case and I'm just not looking in the right place.

Comment: You mean [an interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) ?

Answer (score 2):

Header only libraries are written as `INTERFACE libraries` in CMake lingo.

EX:

```
# Header only library
add_library(htcw_bits INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(htcw_bits INTERFACE
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/htcw_bits/include"
)

add_library(htcw_io lib/htcw_io/src/io_stream.cpp)
target_include_directories(htcw_io PUBLIC
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/htcw_io/include"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
)

# By "linking" htcw_bits we avoid manually adding the include directory
# creating a nice abstraction
target_link_libraries(htcw_io PRIVATE htcw_bits)
```

Comment: `htcw_io` should link to `htcw_bits` rather than including its directory explicitly.

Comment: Updated example code.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - thank you so much!